# adding controls to a Windows Forms Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm struggling to correctly add controls (actually these are objects which I have created) to the panel in the Form1.cs. Example, MusicNote class is a picture box object which when it is instantiated FROM FORM1_LOAD METHOD and added to MusicStaff object (another class) which is then added to panel it works fine. See below...

```
MusicStaff ms;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ms = new MusicStaff();
    panel2.Controls.Add(ms);

    //Test of Music Note
    MusicNote musNote = new MusicNote(1, "");
    ms.Controls.Add(musNote);
```

The problem is that I want the MusicNote to be created and Added to ms and panel2 (which are different classes) when a button is pressed. I have a button click event on another class which is working fine. The problem is that ms and panel2 are not accessible from that class and I don't know how to get access to them. I know that if I create new instances of MusicStaff and Form1 they will be new object and not the actual ones.

```
        protected void MusKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
            txt1.Text = Convert.ToString(musicNote); //To test if musicNote refers to   the correct pitch integer.
            MusicNote musNote = new MusicNote(this.musicNote, " ");
            //HERE I NEED THE CODE TO ADD MUSNOTE TO MUSICSTAFF WHICH IS ALREADY ADDED TO THE PANEL IN FORM1.CS }
```

I hope I explained what I need clearly enough...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create MusicNote and  ms  as private static class field and make them as  public static property

```
     static MusicStaff ms;
     statuc MusicNote musNote 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ms = new MusicStaff();
    panel2.Controls.Add(ms);

    //Test of Music Note
    musNote = new MusicNote(1, "");
    ms.Controls.Add(musNote);

public static MusicStaff Ms
{ 
   get {return ms; }
}


public static MusicNote Mn
{ 
   get {return ms; }
}
```

to access controls  just use

```
  Form1.Ms or Form1.Mn
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough... what I want to achieve is the be able to access panel2 from the other classes.... e.g. Form1.panel2.Controls.Add(musicNote) but Form1.panel2 will not work in c#..

Comment: @JulieShannon, you'll have to mark `ms` and `musNote` as `public` or at least `internal` for that.

Comment: Thank You for your help it worked fine... however I've done this only for MusicStaff since  only need one music staff.. however I cannot do this with MusicNote since I will be creating different MusicNotes when different keys are pressed. The notes will then be display on the sinlge MusicStaff object.

Comment: One last question.. how can I set a panel e.g. panel2 to static like I've done with ms and musNote since I didn't declare it myself and can't see the code ..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one of two ways. Easy one first:

Just declare your MusicStaff control **outside** of the Form1_Load method (make it a field on the form).

```
MusicStaff ms = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ms = new MusicStaff();
   //etc...
}
```

Secondly, you could retrieve the control from the Controls collection using Linq. This line assumes there's only one control of type MusicStaff in the collection:

```
var ms = Controls.First(c => c is MusicStaff) as MusicStaff;
```

Comment: I can't comment on Julies post, but her answer is essentially the same as mine, EXCEPT one should NOT make the field a static. If you do this, ALL instances of your form will share this one control. Adding a note to one will add it to all. I highly doubt this is your desired behavior.

Comment: The first way is exactly the same thing what I've done... correct me if i'm wrong..

Comment: I think that what I've replied to Julie is what you have pointed out regarding MusicNotes... Tks

Comment: +1 for the second approach. Much better choice then `static`-stuff(well, at least it won't kill dolphins, but `static` will). Also, in case of multiple `MusicStaff` instances it will be pretty easy to get specific musicstaff instance by filtering like `Controls.OfType<MusicStaff>().Where(s => s.StaffName == "blah")`

Comment: Maybe you are right but I really don't know nothing about Linq :)

Comment: You're right. I didn't see the outer declaration.

In that case, you should be able to access the MusicStaff object from anywhere in the form.

Again, do NOT make it static. You don't want the MusicStaff control shared between forms, even if you only plan to have one form in your application. That will come back and bite you later!

Comment: One other thing I noticed... you might want to add an Add(musicnote) method to your MusicStaff object, and then have that method take care of adding the note to the MusicStaff's controls collection. This provides better encapsulation and gives the control a chance to do any housekeeping (redrawing, etc) required when a note is added.

Answer (score 0):

*The problem is that ms and panel2 are not accessible from that class and I don't know how to get access to them.* This is because a Form's controls have `private` visibility by default. Generally this is a good thing, to prevent [excessive coupling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc947917.aspx) between a Form and other objects, including other Forms. You can change a control's `Visibility` property using the VS form designer.

A better approach in my opinion is to make each object as self-sufficient as possible, to minimise dependency between objects (as discussed in the link above). So for example, the Form that displays/edits the music staff should be fully responsible for creating/moving/deleting the staff and any notes or other notation on the staff. Then other objects can *ask* the staff Form to make changes on the staff instead of making the changes directly. You could do this by adding a public/internal method to Form1, `AddMusicNote(int value, string description)`, then call it from the other class/Form :

```
protected void MusKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Green;
    txt1.Text = Convert.ToString(musicNote); //To test if musicNote refers to   the correct pitch integer.
    form1.AddMusicNote(musicNote, " ");
}
```